# how to get the path upto webapps folder of tomcat in servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets

> i am trying to get the tomcat webapps folder based on environment
>   where i deployed i tried the bellow code

```
String path= ctx.getRealPath("/");
op:C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\myapp
```

this is giving upto root of the application i want to get the path upto webapps 
with out using any string removal on "path"

are there any other methods in context can provide me the tomcat webapps  path ?
 anyone can help me one this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When tomcat starts up it registers a system property called `catalina.base` you can do something like this

```
String tomcatBase = System.getProperty("catalina.base");
```

This will return (for your example) `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0`

Then from there for a standard installation you can get to your webapp by doing

```
String webApp = String.format("%s/webapps/myapp", tomcatBase);
```

Then regardless of where you deploy tomcat, the path will always work.