# run Java Servlet unit tests on Tomcat server

Tags: java, unit-testing, tomcat, servlets

I have a Java HttpServlet. When we send a get Request to this servlet, it checks whether a file in the server exist or not. if not create a new file.

I want to write some unit tests. When a get request sends, assert that the new file created. 
My problem is my tests running on my local machine, not the Tomcat Server and temp files created in the local server.

here is my code:

```
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("localhost:8080/myfilename");
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    File directory = new File("myfilename");

    // then
    assertTrue(directory.exists());
```

how to run the unit tests, on the tomcat server?

Comment: You can get [local path of Tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748318/how-to-get-the-path-upto-webapps-folder-of-tomcat-in-servlet), it's independent from the machine

Answer (score 2):

Distinct non-answer: you don't do that.

Long answer: **unit** tests are about testing **units** in **isolation**. And in order to be useful, you mock/stub anything external, such as: a web or application server.

In other words: a **real** unit test should be written for the code that your server invokes for a specific URL. You could write a decent unit test that ensures: "when I am called, I check for that file, if not, create it".

Then you test that, independent of any Tomcat server.

Then, later on, you might want to test that your **end to end** feature works. But of course, then you should only be using APIs that your *server* itself has to offer.

Comment: @MoRtEzATM From a less test-fundamentalist perspective you could use the painful (but only) [arquillian](http://arquillian.org/blog/tags/tomcat/) for such kind of things. The complications involved with that will naturally limit such tests to a minimum.

Comment: @gurioso Sure. But the point is: one should really *know* what all these terms mean. When you don't understand the test pyramid, then you have to learn the fundamentals first. Otherwise chances are that anything that comes out of your work ... will not make much sense ;-)